Reshape freeform shape in Excel with VBA
I'm trying to animate a "doodle" shape (freeform) in Excel using VBA, but I’m having trouble getting it to move. I was able to animate a connector shape with the following code, which adjusts the curve of the connector in an "S" shape:
Sub Macro3()

   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Curved Connector 2")).Select
   Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.71994
   tiempo (0.25)
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Curved Connector 2")).Select
   Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.59967
   tiempo (0.25)
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Curved Connector 2")).Select
   Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.48627
   tiempo (0.25)
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Curved Connector 2")).Select
   Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.35912
   tiempo (0.25)
End Sub

Where
Sub tiempo(duration_ms As Double)
Start_time = Timer
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until (Timer - Start_time) >= duration_ms

End Sub

However, when I try to apply a similar approach to a "doodle" (or freeform) shape, it doesn’t move. I tried recording a macro while manually adjusting the shape, but when I replay the macro, nothing happens.
Has anyone animated freeform shapes in Excel before? How can I move the vertices of a doodle shape programmatically using VBA? Any tips or code examples would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Read: ShapeNodes.SetPosition method (Excel)
ShapeNodes.SetPosition
Sets the location of the node specified by Index. Note that, depending on the editing type of the node, this method may affect the position of adjacent nodes.



Name
Required/Optional
Data Type
Description




Index
Required
Long
The node whose position is to be set.


X1
Required
Single
The position (in points) of the new node relative to the upper-left corner of the document.


Y1
Required
Single
The position (in points) of the new node relative to the upper-left corner of the document.



This is my test setup.  I created a couple of shapes to work with.  During each test I'll duplicate a shape and name it Snake.  Next I record the Shapes Vertices.  The Vertices are the same values as the Nodes Values.

Typing your variable properly will make it easier to write your code.  If you are not sure what Type an object is insert a stop, run your code and use ?TypeName() in the Immediate Window to get its type.

?TypeName(Sheet4.Shapes("Snake"))


Shape


Sub Test()
    Dim Snake As Shape
    Set Snake = Sheet4.Shapes("Snake")
    
    Dim Nodes As ShapeNodes
    Set Nodes = Snake.Nodes

    Dim FirstNode As ShapeNode
    Set FirstNode = Nodes(1)
    
    Nodes.SetPosition 1, FirstNode.Points(1, 2) + 10, FirstNode.Points(1, 2) + 10
    Stop
End Sub


Sub RecordVerticies()
    Dim Snake As Shape
    Set Snake = Sheet4.Shapes("Snake")
  
    Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("X", "Y")
    Range("A2").Resize(Nodes.Count, 2).Value = Snake.Vertices
End Sub

It isn't intuitive to me how to predict the changes in node position because they are relative to the upper left hand corner of the document(worksheet).
